# Bobby Fischer photos in his NY apartment?

Tags: fischer

Are there any photos of young Bobby Fischer in his NY apartment?

Comment: Maybe the fourth picture in this article: http://time.com/3734140/bobby-fischer-mind-games/

Comment: Uhm... I might be wrong, but I don't think he could afford such a chessboard back in 1962... plus all those books, if it were his apartment, should have been chess books, since he studied only chess, right? But for some reason they don't look like chess books to me. Nice photo, anyway! Thank you.

Comment: If he could afford an apartment surely he could afford such a chessboard? What would chess books in 1962 look like, as opposed to any other books? And in which other apartment (with such a chessboard) would he meet up with a photographer?

Comment: I wouldn't see Fischer as someone who needed such an expensive chessboard, but I might be wrong. Perhaps he won it. Regarding the books, I can't say for sure that these aren't chess books, but on the other side if they were chess books, we chessplayers could recognize at least a couple of them from the spine or else. Nothing reminds me of chess in that photo apart the chessboard.

Comment: The 1962-Fischer boasts with his expensive shoes and suits and generally is pretty much a snob, so an expensive chessboard would certainly fit in well. http://bobbyfischer.net/bobby04.html

Comment: I vividly remember a photo of a young Bobby Fischer playing chess in his bathtub, which I think was published in New In Chess sometimes between 2008 and 2012, but it doesn't seem to be findible online. Bobby was analysing a position from some Nimzo-Indian variation.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Here are two pictures of Bobby Fischer (Robert James Fischer), in a New York apartment, mainly taken from the movie (documentary) Bobby Fischer Against The World.(I have no rights to this pictures ,but I think I can post them in some networking sites).

Comment: And this picture also file:///C:/Users/IND/Downloads/rfshr.jpg

Comment: You can't add a local file here.

Comment: Are you sure it's legal to post them here? Also, we (fortunately) have no access to your C-drive.

Comment: Information is not always legally known.